# How to make a div sitting on the bottom of another div with unknown height of any of them

Tags: html, css, height

I have these divs:

```
<div class='jama'>
    <div class='prispevky'> Blogger posts, photos and so one. So I don't know the height of this div. </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, that the outer div called "jama" has to be 400px or more tall:

```
.jama {
        width: 488px;
        background-image: url(&quot;https://www.googledrive.com/host/0B7-fhunaThR4fkRLX0VqQTNPRGx6enF3QUoxMmUxWkdDYl84djFRYk80Qy04UzA2dm93R1k/jama.png&quot;);
        background-position: top;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        margin: 0 auto;
        min-height: 400px;
}
```

Is there a way how to make the div called "prispevky" always on the bottom of the div called "jama"?

Answer (score 1):

Set `position:relative` on `.jama`, then on `.prispevky` set `position:absolute` and `bottom:0;left:0;right:0;`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
```

Comment: i need to sit the div to the bottom of the outer div, not to the bottom of my screen..

Answer (score 0):

You need to set css `position` property of `.jama` to `relative`. Put `#prispevky` div inside `.jama` and set its css `position` property to `absolute` and `bottom` property to `0`. Here is an example:

```css
.jama {
  width: 488px;
  min-height: 200px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

#prispevky {
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="jama">
  <div id="prispevky">
    Div with unknown height Div with unknown height Div with unknown height Div with unknown height Div with unknown height Div with unknown height Div with unknown height Div with unknown height Div with unknown height 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but the height of prispevky is also unknown, so i cant set the height of this div..

Comment: @user3473897 it is just for example. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: but when the div "prispevky" is bigger than 200px, than I cant see him whole.. :(